# Dio Makes Many API calls in Scroll Controller listener

Tags: android, flutter, dart, infinite-scroll, dio

I used Dio to call APIs in scroll Controller , i was expecting 1 http call , but its calling about 80 times without any reason ..

the code :

```
 int i=0;

 @override
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
 }

 void _scrollListener() {
    _scrollController.addListener(() async {
  if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
    print("FIRED");
    var dio = new Dio();
    var url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20&offset=" + (20).toString();
    dio.get(url).then((response){
      setState(() {
        i++;
      });
      print("----------------------------------------------------"+i.toString()+"------------------------------------");
      print("API CALLED ...");
    });
  }
 });
}
```

and this is the log :

```
    I/flutter (10743): FIRED
    I/flutter (10743): FIRED
    I/flutter (10743): ----------------------------------------------------1------------------------------------
    I/flutter (10743): API CALLED ...
    I/flutter (10743): ----------------------------------------------------2------------------------------------
    I/flutter (10743): API CALLED ...
    I/flutter (10743): ----------------------------------------------------3------------------------------------
    I/flutter (10743): API CALLED ...
    I/flutter (10743): ----------------------------------------------------4------------------------------------
    I/flutter (10743): API CALLED ...
    I/flutter (10743): ----------------------------------------------------5------------------------------------
    I/flutter (10743): API CALLED ... 
    I/flutter (10743): ----------------------------------------------------6------------------------------------
    I/flutter (10743): API CALLED ...
    I/flutter (10743): ----------------------------------------------------80------------------------------------
    I/flutter (10743): API CALLED ...
```

as you can see in the log , "FIRED" wrote only 2 times and that's OK , but "API CALLED" wrote 80 times , and sometimes even more .

I just don't know why Dio.get called about 80 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for responding you late.
Problem is in your initState, means You  are making nested attachment to the addListener. inside _scrollListener() you have already attached a addListener to your ScrollController, then you also call  _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener).

Solution

[image]

Problem with your code

[image]